# Sharing multiple internet connections though a single server

Tags: windows-xp, networking, internet-sharing

I'm having a 3 separate Internet connections which are connected through through the router for each PC.

I would like to know is it possible to combine all these connections and share the connection through the separate server?  So the server shares all the Internet?

If it’s possible how can I do it?  Need a solution in Windows XP

And also is it possible to limit maximum file size that can be downloaded through the server?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how this is working.  You have three internet connections coming through a single router or multiple routers?  If you could share all three, what method would you want to use to determine which of the three connections was used for traffic - source, destination, random, what?